# On understanding blogger template macros and sections

Tags: html, xml, blogger

What's the difference between
`<b:section-contents id='xx'>` and `<b:section>`?
Or

```
 <aside>
   <macro:include id='main-column-right-sections' name='sections'>
     <macro:param default='2' name='num' value='1'/>
     <macro:param default='sidebar-right' name='idPrefix'/>
     <macro:param default='sidebar' name='class'/>
     <macro:param default='true' name='includeBottom'/>
   </macro:include>
 </aside>
```

What's aside for in this context? What is macro? How do these things affect the templates?

Answer (score 0):

First, aside stands for sidebar according to [HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp).
Second, macro is a Blogger XML function which allow user to change template layout dynamically by Blogger template designer. [more info about blogger macro.](http://sneeit.com/2015/06/understanding-about-blogger-macro-xml-template-code.html)